# How to install postgres 13.1?

Tags: postgresql

How to install postgresql 13.1

I'm trying

```
# Create the file repository configuration:
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt $(lsb_release -cs)-pgdg     main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list'

# Import the repository signing key:
wget --quiet -O - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | sudo apt-key add -

# Update the package lists:
sudo apt-get update

# Install the latest version of PostgreSQL.
# If you want a specific version, use 'postgresql-12' or similar instead of 'postgresql':
sudo apt-get -y install postgresql-13.1
```

[Source on postgresql.org](https://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/ubuntu/)

But I got this:

> E: Unable to locate package postgresql-13.1

> E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'postgresql-13.1'

> E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'postgresql-13.1'

If I'm trying

```
sudo apt-get -y install postgresql-13
```

or

```
sudo apt-get -y install postgresql-12
```

It's working, but 'sudo apt-get -y install postgresql-13' installes the last version of postgresql-13 (13.3) and I need 13.1

Can I do it via terminal (because I use bash script)?

Comment: Why do you want to install a version that has known bugs that are fixed in a later (minor) release? What is so special about 13.1 that you can't use the latest bugfix version? It's highly recommended to always run the latest minor version. [Quote from the homepage](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/) "*For minor releases, **the community considers not upgrading to be riskier than upgrading***"

Comment: Because that version is what customer certificated and they don't want any other...

Comment: Then tell them running 13.1 is a security risk - you should always run the most recent bugfix version. And maybe you want to confirm with them, that they actually mean the major version "13" in general, and not one specific patch release (maybe they still think that 13.1 to 13.3 is a major version upgrade because they didn't realize the change in versioning that happened with Postgres 10)

Comment: Okay, I'll try, thanks